# How do I make many system calls at once with the linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I was wondering if I could make a large number of system calls at the same time, with only one switch overhead. I need this because I have a need to make many (128) system calls at the same time. If I could do this without switching between kernel and userland 256+ times I think it could make my (speed sensitive) library significantly faster.

Comment: If you're serious that switching between user context and kernel context is unacceptably expensive ... then use an OS that doesn't *have* any context switching.  Like DOS, for example.  IMHO...  ALSO: look at this article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-real-time-linux/

Comment: My library is throughput sensitive, not realtime.

Comment: Also, it wouldn't be expensive if I didn't have to do it 128 times in a row.

Comment: @NotaName: You've built a library that requires at least 128 concurrent system calls, you haven't got any benchmarks or profiles but have a hunch that you'd have a 50% speed up? I can *guarantee* you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaK It isn't done yet, so I can't benchmark it (doesn't even compile yet), but I know I'm going to need those calls. I'm guessing it's going to be faster than that, about the most expensive operation outside of system calls is finding the index of a series of 0 bits amoung a 64bit type.

Comment: You're definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: Just in case this is an XY problem: What 128 syscalls are you doing? Sometimes there are better APIs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You really can't do that from an application program.  What you *could* do is build a loadable kernel module that implements those operations and presents a simple API -- then you can change context once, do all the work, and return.

However, as with most of these sorts of optimization questions, the first thing to ask is "why do you think it's going to be necessary?"  Do you have timing information etc?  Have you profiled?  How much of a performance issue do you really have, and is the additional complexity going to be worth the speedup?

Comment: I have no profiling information because I haven't quite finished my library yet (not usable). But I know that syscalls are relatively slow (compared to everything else I'm doing), and my library doesn't need to spend 90% of the time switching contexts and dealing with switch overhead. But I estimate that a 50% speedup of this library will speed-up applications that use it by about 5-10%.

Comment: Kernel module will execute in kernel space and you will not have interrupts and context switches as much as executing system calls from user space.

Comment: @NotaName, Ask yourself what would be the ration between syscall overhead, syscall useful work and non-syscall useful work. Normally, the overhead would be small compared to the other two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Linux will support syscall chaining anytime soon. You might have more luck implementing this on another kernel and porting your application.

That said, it's not difficult to write a proxy to do the job in kernelspace for you, but don't expect it to be merged upstream. I've worked on real-time stuff and we had a solution like that, but never used in production because of support issues :/.